# Inputenc error with spanish

Tags: errors, accents, input-encodings, spanish

I'm currently writing my final thesis in TeXstudio and for a better organization I'm writing each chapter in a different text file. I'm also writing in Spanish and as far as I know, the `inputenc` package with `utf8` configuration (`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`) along the `babel` package (`\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}`) must be ok for that. I started to write the first chapter with Spanish accents without any problem, nevertheless as soon as I started writing chapter 2 there was an `inputenc` error whenever I typed an accented word or the letter `ñ`. The error is like this:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: étr not set up for use with LaTeX
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: ño not set up for use with LaTeX
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: ón not set up for use with LaTeX
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: És not set up for use with LaTeX
etc.
etc.
.
.
.
```

I don't really get it since I wrote chapter 1 without problems. I'm using those lines to add the chapters to the main file.

```
\input{Capitulo1}
\input{Capitulo2}
\input{Capitulo3}
\input{Capitulo4}
\input{Capitulo5}
```

It's as if TeXtstudio wouldn't keep recognizing the `inputenc` function after the first `\input{file.tex}` or something. And the wiered thing is that the inputenc error is for the accented words interacting inside a word, for example `étr` or `ño` inside the words `paramétrico` and `diseño`.

I can only make it work if I place the whole chapter's 2 content into the chapter's 1 TeX file.

Any ideas?

Comment: you say the problem disappears when you copy `Capitulo2.tex's` content into `Capitulo1.tex`. What happens when you create a copy of `Capitulo1.tex`, rename it to `Capitulo2a` (or whatever) and copy `Capitulo2's` content into that file?

Comment: Your second file is not utf8 encoded. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105672/special-characters-in-input-file

Comment: Brilliant! just as you said my second file was not `UTF-8` encoded! It was `ANSI` encoded and I don't know why since I created the whole files at once. However, in order to show the answer to this problem, what I done was to check the `tex` file codification within notepad, then I realized that some of my files as `Capitulo1` and the main file were in UTF-8, but some others as `Capitulo2` were ANSI coded, so I just opened them, saved them with the same name but with `UTF-8` codification, then reopened them in Textstudio and the problem was solved! Thanks again!

Comment: Although Nils L's method would have also worked since `Capitulo1.tex` was `UTF-8` coded.

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

If it doesn't work, then try (For iso-8859-1):

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

Write in normal spanish, don't worry about special characters (i.e. use "diseño", you don't have to write "dise\~no").

This should work just fine.  It does for me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @egreg,
Thank you for the editing.  I wanted it to be that way, I'm just kind of getting used to the site.